# Power MOSFETs used as a switch in DC/DC converter circuits in saturation region

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, boost, switching, buck-boost

So I have explored various high voltage DC/DC converter circuits. Consider a boost converter where you have a low side switch where entire load voltage appears across the switch which is MOSFET VDS and can go as high as 100 to thousands of volts. In this case, it would be pretty difficult to operate a MOSFET in linear region. So in power circuits like these, are MOSFETs always operated in saturation region? Doesn't that make switching very inefficient? Or am I missing something?

Comment: why do you think a high blocking drain source voltage makes conduction in the saturation regime more likely?

Comment: Don’t confuse mosfet operation with bjts. With bjts, they are slow to turn off if saturated, thus causing losses. Mosfets on the other hand you want saturated (as in fully turned on) to minimise losses. Two different mechanisms at play.

Comment: @tobalt since Voltage between drain and source is greater than overdrive voltage

Comment: @kartman I am not confusing with BJTs. From CMOS background, MOSFETs are operated in saturation mode during amplification and textbooks say linear mode during switching, Here is another stack exchange link that says power dissipation increases in saturation: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/553748/use-mosfet-as-a-switch-in-saturation-region#:~:text=use%20MOSFET%20as%20a%20switch%20in%20saturation%20region%20%2D%20Electrical%20Engineering%20Stack%20Exchange

Comment: of course one uses them in the Ohmic mode for switching. The necessary VGS doesnt depend on the blocking drain voltage, but on active current.

Comment: @tobalt Check this out: https://imgur.com/a/fVMYFC9. A high drain voltage of the order of 100s of volts will push the MOS into saturation, unless you match the gate voltage upto that which is rarely the case.

Comment: You are confusing off-state drain voltage (100s of V) with on-state drain voltage (ID * Ron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer by V.V.T](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642402/237061) has all the details. But as your questions in comment still point to a flaw in your understanding, I will add another answer. Taking the image from your comment:

[image]

The key mistake in your understanding is that you look at this graphic and think *"High drain-source-voltage means saturation regime"*.

However, this applies only when the switch is off. If you will, it is *saturated* at ~0 A and ~0 V between the gate and source (*cut-off*). The power dissipation is negligible because there is no current.

When the switch turns on, whatever source is driving the FET will source only finite current, e.g. the current through an inductor. Therefore, the drain-source voltage will collapse to a low value of \$I_D\cdot R_{on}\$, which is a tiny fraction of the full input voltage. So the MOSFET enters the ohmic region. The remaining voltage is dropping over the current source that is driving the FET.

During the switching instant, the FET is still in the saturation region, and - you are right - this time has to be made as short as possible to not fry the FET due to the extreme power dissipation in this phase.